# Load Testing of UI User scenario - Jmeter Webdriver sampler

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I want to run basic load testing scenario on a mendix application.
The initial requirement is at least 10 users should be able to perform some activities like login , file upload concurrently.
I have used the webdriver sampler in Jmeter with selenium and written the JS script for the actions.
The issue is it launches 10 browser on the same machine.

- Please suggest the proper way to handle this. Currently it seems that the errors which I am getting are because of I am running the test on my laptop instead of distributed setup.
- Also the total script takes 60 seconds to finish for single user. What should be the ramp up time?
- If not Jmeter, please suggest any other suitable tool for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As per [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article

> **Q. How do I Allocate the WebDriver Sampler?**

> A. First of all, **don’t use the WebDriver Sampler to create the load!** You’ll need around 1 CPU core per virtual user to keep the JMeter resource consumption within an acceptable range. The WebDriver Sampler should be used in addition to HTTP Request Samplers. Here’s an example of how it should be used:

> - 1,000 of users are simulated by HTTP Request Samplers

> - 1 user is the WebDriver Sampler

> You should use the WebDriver Sampler to evaluate a real-life user experience. It’s most commonly used to measure the load times of pages when the system is experiencing high loads. The HTTP Request doesn’t really “render” the page and it can’t execute JavaScript. That’s why the WebDriver Sampler is so valuable - JMeter isn’t a browser and it overcomes limitations posed by this fact.

So first of all I would recommend re-considering your approach and migrating to [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, you might be able to execute 10 browsers but if you will need to scale your test to 100 or 1000 users you will definitely won't be able to use this "real browser" approach while HTTP Request samplers act on HTTP protocol level, given you properly configure JMeter it will be no difference for the application under test whether the requests are originating from JMeter or from the real browser and the resources footprint will be much less.

---

With regards to the ramp-up time: the overall idea is to increase the load **gradually** so you could correlate the changing number of virtual users with changing metrics like response time, throughput, etc. According to JMeter Documentation:

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.

> **Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish** (unless one wants that to happen).

> Start with `Ramp-up = number of threads` and adjust up or down as needed.